# UIImage not Saving

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, qr-code, xcode9

Currently losing the will to live trying to work out why this isn't working!
Basically I have generated a QR code (Swift 4/Xcode 9) and displayed this within a UIImageView. I would like to save this image to be used in a popup view elsewhere in the app.
My code to generate the QR Code is as follows:

```
func generateQRCode(from string: NSString) -> UIImage? {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.isoLatin1.rawValue, allowLossyConversion: false)
    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
        guard let colorFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIFalseColor") else { return nil }

        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")

        filter.setValue("H", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")
        colorFilter.setValue(filter.outputImage, forKey: "inputImage")
        colorFilter.setValue(CIColor(red: 255/255, green: 87/255, blue: 34/255, alpha: 1), forKey: "inputColor1") // Background ORANGE
        colorFilter.setValue(CIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1), forKey: "inputColor0") // Foreground or the barcode WHITE
        guard let qrCodeImage = colorFilter.outputImage
            else {
                return nil
        }
        let scaleX = myQRCode.frame.size.width / qrCodeImage.extent.size.width
        let scaleY = myQRCode.frame.size.height / qrCodeImage.extent.size.height
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleX, y: scaleY)


        if let output = colorFilter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {
            return UIImage(ciImage: output)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

I then run the following code in viewDidLoad to display the QR code image:

```
let image = generateQRCode(from: jsonString)
    myImageView.image = image
```

I then get the documents directory path and attempt to save the image:

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return paths[0]
}

func saveQRImage() {
    if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImageView.image!) {
        let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("qrcode.png")
        try? data.write(to: filename)
        print(data)
    }
}
```

I have tried calling the `saveQRImage()` function on both viewDidLoad and on a button press but neither are saving the image. I have placed a breakpoint after the first if let statement in `saveQRImage()` but find that it is not running the function.

I have tried declaring an empty UIImage variable called `finishedQRCode` and saying `finishedQRCode = myImageView.image` and using this in the `saveQRImage()` function instead, but this makes no difference!

Is there something really simple that I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: replace `try?` with do-catch block. If `try` failed, the catch block will be called And you can print the error.

Comment: I cannot give you an exact answer yet as I don't have enough information. It appears that after running `generateQRCode` that image is nil. so you need to add a breakpoint in this function and step through it. Personally, I would comment out the colour filter and try it as basic as possible and confirm thats working and then add the colour filter back in and see if that makes a difference. Also you need to ensure that the JSON string is valid. Can you actually make a QR code from a JSON String? I thought it was mostly URLs?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327921/qr-codes-limits. JSON data is pretty useless in a QR code

Comment: Thank you for you're unbelievably quick replies! I'll try and provide a bit more information based on your points. The `generateQRCode` function seems to be working fine as I am able to obtain a UIImage to display in my UIImageView (i.e. the generated QR Code image). Regarding the JSON string, the QR code is generated perfectly with no issues. I have just tried the process with a basic string and still have the same problem.

Comment: if the image is generated then why dont you save the image in db ? why DocumentsDirectory ?  ..

Comment: After reading online, documents directory seemed the obvious place to save the image to. I wasn't aware it would be just as simple to save to a db?

Comment: UPDATE: I've removed the colour filter and just created a bog-standard black and white QR code. Still got the same issue. Placing breakpoints I find that it will not go past `if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImageView.image!)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation` from a ciimage. You need to redraw your image in a new context:

```
let size = CGSize(width: scaleX, height: scaleY)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
UIImage(ciImage: output).draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
if let qrcodeImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
   let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(qrcodeImage, 1)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! However I am unsure as to how I implement this into my project? I have placed this in my `generateQRCode()` function prior to `return UIImage(ciImage: output)` is this correct? How do I then save the imageData?

Comment: Just data.write(to URL

Comment: Marked as answer. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Image seems to be quite fuzzy when rendered in my popup image view. That's something I'll have to have a play around with now.

Comment: You need to scale your image but looks like you did already applied transformation. Make sure you are scaling it up

Comment: Try with creating your QRCode image using size 256x256 minimum for small strings and for large strings 1024x1024